# "Provides no initializer for reference member..."

Tags: c++, oop, object

After some search on google, I cannot find an answer to this error. How do I initialize it, and why do I need to?

```
#include "CalculatorController.h"


CalculatorController::CalculatorController(SimpleCalculator& aModel, ICalculatorView& aView)
{ \\(this is the bracket informing me of the error)
   fModel = aModel;
   fView = aView;
}
```

header:

```
#pragma once

#include  "ICalculatorView.h"
#include "SimpleCalculator.h"

class CalculatorController
{
private:
   SimpleCalculator& fModel;
   ICalculatorView& fView;

public:
   CalculatorController(SimpleCalculator& aModel, ICalculatorView& aView);

   void run();
   ~CalculatorController();
};
```

Comment: Reference and `const` members must be initialized in a member-initialization list. You don't have one (but you're about to). See this question: ["What is this weird colon-member (“ : ”) syntax in the constructor?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor).

Comment: Why `const` and reference member variables must be initialized in a member-initialization list? For reference member variables because references are basically constants [Once initialized, a reference cannot be changed to refer to another object.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization)
For `cosnt` member variables see an example [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/8-5a-constructor-member-initializer-lists/)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of:

```
CalculatorController::CalculatorController(SimpleCalculator& aModel, ICalculatorView& aView)
{\\(this is the bracket informing me of the error)

fModel = aModel;
fView = aView;
}
```

Use

```
CalculatorController::CalculatorController(SimpleCalculator& aModel, ICalculatorView& aView) 
 : fModel(aModel),fView(aView)
{
}
```

fModel and fView are reference member. Different instances of CalculatorController can share the same instances fModel and fView this way, without using nasty pointer.

Reference member have to be initialized on creation. My second code block show how to.

Comment: so how do i get fModel and fView to refer to anything?